# Adding non-script or css elements to visual force head

Tags: visualforce, javascript

Its it possible to add things other than simple scripts or css to a visual force page ?

Examples:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20130526/json2.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<base href="{!URLFOR($Resource.SalesCentralApp, 'SalesCentralApp/app/')}" />
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
```

I'm working with an angular app, and while chrome will actually detect the double head and combine the elements, IE 8 is not that smart...

Answer (score 1):

Now, Visualforce has some very useful attributes to resolve these issues on apex:page tag. We can utilize them if building Angular app.

Refer the document [apex:page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_page.htm) tag.

On the apex page tag, provide attributes this way:

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" showheader="false" sidebar="false" standardstylesheets="false" applyHTMLTag="false" applyBodyTag="false">
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <title>Example - example-guide-concepts-1-production</title>      
    </head>
    <body>
        <c:AngualarApp/>
    </body>
  </html>
</apex:page>
```

Above will be rendered as no conflict HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

  <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="/static/111213/js/perf/stub.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/jslibrary/1466812160000/sfdc/VFMetadataSender.js" type="text/javascript"></script><meta HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE" />
        <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" content="Mon, 01 Jan 1990 12:00:00 GMT" />

        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
        <title>Example - example-guide-concepts-1-production</title>      
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
  </html>
  <script type="text/javascript">  SfdcApp.Visualforce.viewstate.ViewstateSender.sendViewstate('https://ashwaniarea-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com', 'NoDefaultHTMLTags');  </script>
```

Comment: that only works if you don't need the app to show up with the Standard Salesforce header